# Worin liegt der Unterschied

Tags: difference

Worin liegt der Unterschied zwischen diesen beiden Sätzen:

```
Ich konnte die Aufgabe nicht lösen.
```

und

```
Ich habe die Aufgabe nicht lösen können.
```

Drückt einer der beiden einen gescheiterten Versuch, und der andere den Fall, dass man in der Vergangenheit keine Möglichkeit gehabt hatte, die Aufgabe zu lösen, aus?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Es besteht kein Bedeutungsunterschied. In manchen Gegenden (vor allem im Süden des deutschen Sprachraums) wird umgangssprachlich das Perfekt anstelle des Präteritums verwendet.

---

Eine andere Bedeutung hätte nur das Plusquamperfekt:

> Ich hatte die Aufgabe nicht lösen können.

Dann bezieht sich die Aussage auf einen Zeitpunkt in der Vergangenheit. Das kann bedeuten, dass es zu irgendeinem Zeitpunkt darauf ankam, dass man die Aufgabe bis zu diesem Zeitpunkt lösen hätte können ("Ich hatte die Aufgabe nicht lösen können. Deshalb konnte ich nicht beim Gewinnspiel mitmachen.") oder dass man sie inzwischen lösen kann ("Ich hatte die Aufgabe nicht lösen können. Deshalb hat mir Hans gezeigt, wie es geht.")